# OAuth Resource Server, validate token and return scopes for endpoint authorization

Tags: c#, .net, oauth-2.0

I am attempting to use the Microsoft.Owin.Security.OAuth library inside of a wrapped custom middleware token validator. This middleware will be loaded on a server that will be receiving a bearer token that will then be passed to the resource server's introspection endpoint and scopes will be returned which will then be used to authorize certain webapi calls.

This validator simply validates the token by making the call to the introspection endpoint. I think I can get by with wrapping the OAuthAuthorizationServer middleware, with my own only requiring information from the consumer necessary for our introspection endpoint.

I have read numerous articles and I must admit that I feel a bit lost. I have tried to simply create a custom middleware that would pull the token off of the authorization header, validate it is a bearer token, call the introspection endpoint, retrieve the scopes and build a ClaimsIdentity. My issue was that I couldn't figure out what I was missing that would hook into the Authorize functionality in ASP.Net.

I have tried to customize some of the OAuthAuthorizationServer and OAuthBearerAuthentication middleware and provide providers that acted similar to my custom middleware, but to no avail. It appears that ultimately I always fail on making a call to an Authorize decorated endpoint.

I can provide code if necessary, but I feel what I am missing is simply direction. I have read many articles involving the OAuthAuthorizationServer, especially the BoT article on decoupling the Authorization Server from the Resource server, but I appear to be missing something.

Any help or direction would be much appreciated, thank you!

Comment: I've done quite a bit of work with oauth over the years. I've found this article the best, and the link to the source code usually contains every example that I've ever needed. Hope it's of use.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/aspnet/overview/owin-and-katana/owin-oauth-20-authorization-server